# Running my application in debug ends without any exceptions being thrown

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using visual studio 2010 sp1, I have an application, and when I run it in debug, the application just stops running. It never pops up highlighting where the unhandled exception occurred, I even have the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException being listened to, and writing any exceptions to a text file, but it never seems to fire.

Any ideas what is going on? If I create a brand new project, and add all my source code to it, it seems to fix it, but eventually whatever setting is being changed is being triggered.

Comment: Some sort of code would be helpful to us. Try writing to a log and see what statements do get printed and which ones don't. Also, check if Environment.FastFail is being used anywhere.

Comment: Well it's a large project, there isn't any specific code. There is no unmanaged code, if there is an exception it should be handled, and if not visual studio usually will highlight it and show what the problem is, but it is just ending execution without saying anything.

Comment: Can you post the debug output after running? (View -> Output -> Select Debug)

Comment: what kind of application is it? Is it Silverlight or windows phone app by any chance?

Comment: What is the exit code in the Output window? My TrendMicro AV seems to cause this quite frequently when debugging web apps.

Comment: Last two lines were:   The program '[2272] WNF.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[2272] WNF.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).